# Related name clash with +

Tags: django

Using Django 1.6.5

All my models in this one app have a related_name='+' yet I'm still getting this error.   Has Django lost it's marbles?

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class StaffGroup(models.Model):
    agency = models.ForeignKey(Agency)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='+')
```

Error Message

```
messaging.staffgroup: Accessor for m2m field 'users' clashes with related m2m field 'User.+'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'users'.
```

Changing users to staff_users still generates the same error with just a few words changed.

```
messaging.staffgroup: Accessor for m2m field 'staff_users' clashes with related m2m field 'User.+'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'staff_users'.
```

Comment: try to change  '+' for another name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a bug, ManyToMany has a different syntax regarding '+':

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name

You need to specify a unique name for each (for example in your staff model):

```
users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='staff+')
```